# Moving 350,000 EMails with a specific subject from FolderA to FolderB

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a folder by name FolderA.  I have some 350,000 EMails with the subject: "Splunk has been disabled".  I also have another about 45,000 EMails in FolderA which have other subjects.  How can I move all the 350,000 EMails with the subject: "Splunk has been disabled" from FolderA to FolderB ?  I need to ensure that only these 350,000 EMails move from FolderA to FolderB, and that the other 45,000 EMails remain in FolderA.

Can someone let me know how to implement a policy or a Rule to get this done ?  This is in Microsoft Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Outlook Rules to do this.

Beware: Moving 350,000 will take a LONG time (overnight; days).

Outlook Home ribbon, Rules, Create Rule, Advanced and then in the Advanced Window, select Subject and / or other attribute.

"Home Ribbon" is the Ribbon that shows when Outlook first starts.  Make sure you are using the Classic Ribbon and it shows.

[image: Classic Ribbon]

Make certain  Splunk has been disabled  is unique to only the 350,000 emails.

See the descriptive screen shot. Start and then steps 2, 3 and 4 (the rule setup). Subject is part of Body when establishing a Rule.

Any decently modern version of Outlook has this capability.

It may also be that the Opening Rule wizard which allow a specific subject will work for you.

Use the simplest rule setup that works.

The Advanced Section has the capability to move the email after it has arrived (which is what you have), so this may fit better.

[image: Outlook Rule setup]

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your detailed response but unfortunately I do not have the Home button, nor anything called "Advanced" under Rules.

Comment: Just open Outlook. Rules is on the opening Ribbon. Outlook has been that way for years.  I made that extra clear in my answer. Make sure you are using the Classic Ribbon so you can see Rules.

Comment: I added a screen shot of Classic Ribbon. I do not hide things.

Comment: When you click on Rules, select Create Rule. You see the Create Rule window in my answer

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your fabulous help.  I have been trying for a couple of hours to get the Outlook ribbon but it's been impossible to find it or get it.  Let me see what I can do.  Thanks once again.

Comment: I showed how in the first part with the Ribbon screen shot. Did you try that?

Comment: Also, "Ribbon" started with Office 2007 and has been with Office ever since. If it is really not working for you, uninstall Office, restart, and do a fresh install of Office 365.  Then the ribbon will be there and you can proceed as posted.

Answer (score 0):

It’s suggested  that you could refer to the following steps:

1.Click the folder A and filter subject as shown in the below figure.

2.Under the group "Splunk has been disabled", you just click the first and slide down the last message, hold down the Shift key and click to select all messages that contain this subject.

3.Right click to choose Move and choose the folder B.

[image]

Hope to help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.